# Left adjoint to inverse image of sheaves

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

We write $\mathrm{Sh}(X)=\mathrm{Sh}(X, \mathsf{Sets})$ for the category of sheaves of sets on $X$.

In this situation, if $f: X \to Y$ is an etale map (i.e. a local homeomorphism) of topological spaces then we can show that there is a left adjoint $f_!: \mathrm{Sh}(X) \to \mathrm{Sh}(Y)$ to the inverse image functor $f^{-1}: \mathrm{Sh}(Y) \to \mathrm{Sh}(X)$, which corresponds to the [dependent sum](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dependent+sum) $\Sigma_f$ of etale spaces of sheaves.

I am curious if this left adjoint exists if $\mathsf{Sets}$ is replaced by some other complete and cocomplete category $\mathsf{C}$?

If $j: U \hookrightarrow Y$ is the inclusion of an open subset, then $j_!$ exists, and is called the [**extension by $0$**](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/009Z), where $0$ is the initial object in $\mathsf{C}$.

Does a left adjoint $f_!$ still exist if we replace $j: U \hookrightarrow X$ by an arbitary etale map $f: X \to Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the left adjoint do exist if the category is cocomplete and has the solution set criterion, for example if $\mathbf{C}$ is Grothendieck abelian. This follows from the adjoint functor theorem.

Indeed, $f^{-1}$ commutes with finite projective limits, so we just need to check that $f^{-1}$ commute with infinite products. But this can be checked locally since $j^{-1}$ do have a left adjoint for $j:U\rightarrow X$ an open immersion.

More precisely, let $\prod \mathcal{F}_i$ be an arbitrary product of sheaves on $Y$. We need to prove that the natural map $f^{-1}\prod\mathcal{F}_i\rightarrow\prod f^{-1}\mathcal{F}_i$ is an isomorphism. For this, it is enough to prove that this is an isomorphism when restricted on some open cover. So write $X=\bigcup U_j$ where $f_j:U_j\rightarrow X\rightarrow Y$ is an open immersion. Then $(f^{-1}\prod\mathcal{F}_i)_{|U_j}= f_j^{-1}\prod \mathcal{F}_i=\prod f_j^{-1}\mathcal{F}_i=(\prod f^{-1}\mathcal{F}_i)_{|U_j}$.

---

In fact, we have the following construction for $f_!\mathcal{F}$ at least in the case of sheaves of set, abelian groups and $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. This is the sheafification of the presheaf
$$V\subset Y\mapsto \coprod_{s\in Map_Y(V,X)}\mathcal{F}(s(V))$$
where $Map_Y(V,X)$ denote the set of sections $V\rightarrow X$ (a section will necessarily be an homeomorphism onto an open subset of $X$), and the coproduct is taken in the corresponding category (sets, abelian group, $\mathcal{O}_X(V)$-modules).

(Maybe this formula works in arbitrary cocomplete categories, I am not sure...)

---

Finally, there is another reason that this works : the category of sheaves on $X$ is equivalent to the category of sheaves on $Et/X$. Then this is the usual extension by zero functor on sheaves on site.

Comment: Thanks! I assume the existence is just a special case of the adjoint functor theorem? I should really learn to use it.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant, I forgot to add this. I'll edit.

Comment: By the way, for the formula you gave for $f_! \mathcal{F}$ in the case of sheaves of sets, abelian groups, etc., can this be written as a coend/weighted colimit in a nice way?

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ I will have to think about it. I do think so, this is a kind of Yoneda extension, but I am not sure.

Comment: More generally, in the case where $f: X \to Y$ is an open map, do we also get a left adjoint to $f^{-1}$? I can see that by the adjoint functor theorem that at least in the case of the terminal map $t: X \to 1$, which is open, that we should have a left adjoint since $t^{-1}$ constructs the constant sheaf, and the product of modules should give the product of the corresponding constant sheaves.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Good question, I have given some thought but I don't have the answer yet. I will pursue my efforts ;). I just have a description of the left adjoint (call it $\pi_0$) of the constant functor but it is not very enlightening. So let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on $X$, then you can write $\mathcal{F}$ as a colimit over some category $I$ of sheaves of the form ${j_U}_!*$ where $j_U:U\rightarrow X$ is an open inclusion and $*$ is the terminal sheaf on $U$. Then the left adjoint $\pi_0(\mathcal{F})$ is the colimit over $I$ of $\pi_0(U)$.

Comment: There is probably something to say when $X$ is locally connected, but I am not sure. I also don't know yet how does it works if the base space is not a point anymore. Some relative $\pi_0$ perhaps. Anyway, if the map is nice (like a submersion between manifold), there are some chance indeed, since the $f^*$ do have a left adjoint, see Verdier duality. I would be surprised if it works for general open maps though. Maybe you can ask a separate question and someone has an answer...

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar with Verdier duality, but I didn't realize that $f^{-1}$ has a left adjoint for the case of a submersion. I had a look in section 3.3 of Kashiwara & Schapira where they discuss Verdier duality in the context of submersions, but I couldn't find a statement of this. Do you happen to know of a reference for this?

Comment: Also, I asked about the case of open maps [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277351/what-are-the-most-general-conditions-under-which-the-inverse-image-of-sheaves-ha).

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ This is just the fact that $f^*=f^![-n]\otimes\mathfrak{or}$ but the latter has a left adjoint : $f_![n]\otimes\mathfrak{or}$

Comment: Thanks! That looks familiar now that you put it that way.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ I just look at your question on mathoverflow. I didn't know the notion of essentially geometric morphism. I think denoting $f_!$ for the left adjoint of $f^*$ is a bad notation. Some authors write $f_\#$ to avoid the confusion with the pushforward with proper support. Even in the case of $f:X\rightarrow pt$ it is not the same thing. Take $X=\mathbb{R}^*$ and $\mathcal{F}$ the terminal sheaf for instance. As I explained $\pi_0(\mathcal{F})$ is a two elements set then. And in the case of abelian group, with $\mathcal{F}=\mathbb{Z}$, the left adjoint is $\mathbb{Z}\pi_0=\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ From the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+connected+topos), the map $f:X\rightarrow pt$ has a left adjoint iff $X$ is locally connected. They also gave a description of $\pi_0(\mathcal{F})$ I suspected : $\pi_0(\mathcal{F})$ is in fact $\pi_0$ of the corresponding étalé space.